# STM32 - I2C - Write Sequential Data

Tags: stm32

I'm using AT24C512 EEPROM which is 512KB along with my STM32

I'm able to write 128bytes of data at once using

```
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&_EEPROM24XX_I2C,0xa0,Address,I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT,(uint8_t*)data,size_of_data,100)
```

but the issue is that i want to write more data after the data that was just wrote, but the EEPROM will replace the data as the Address is the same

so how can i skip the written address ?

Comment: Hello, please write which STM32 MCU exactly you use.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is not about using HAL with I2C, but hope it will point you*

Just check datasheet (I looking into STM32F0) and you can see that the limit is 255 bytes (register CR2:NBYTES), I'm not sure if there is another limitation in HAL, but using direct access to registers you can sent 255 bytes at once or fragment it and sent how much you want.

For fragmenting there is bit CR2:RELOAD, if you set this, then at the end will be not transfer stopped, and you can update next NBYTES, .. when you will set last block of bytes (which will fit into NBYTES) then clear bit CR2:RELOAD.

This has one disadvantage, that every 255 bytes, you will be interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check the `AT24C512` datasheet page 7.

> If more
>   than 128 data words are transmitted to the EEPROM, the
>   data word address will 
>   “
>   roll over
>   ”
>    and previous data will be
>   overwritten. The address 
>   “
>   roll over
>   ”
>    during write is from the
>   last byte of the current page to the first byte of the same
>   page.